# Using data from JPA queries

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa

I am attempting to write a fairly simply program that can read from and write to a SQL-server database.  I've got the writing-to part down pretty well, but am having difficulty using the JPA queries effectively.  As nearly as I can tell, the only way to actually access and use data retrieved by a query is to store it in an instance or list of the appropriate entity class, like so:

```
Query searchQuery = em.createNamedQuery("Document.findByDocTitle");
searchQuery.setParameter("docTitle", title);
List<Document> docList = searchQuery.getResultList();
```

I'm sure that there must be other means of accessing the data from a query, but if so I haven't been able to find them.

This method has worked for me so far, until I needed to use data from a query across joined tables.  In this case it's a m:n relationship between the "document" and "author" tables.  I obviously can't store the results of a joined query in a list of document objects, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

I realize that the answer is probably something simple that I just don't know about, but I've been googling JPA stuff all day without any luck.  Also, if anyone knows of a good comprehensive book or tutorial for JPA, I would appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

Comment: accessing the data from a query? You mean getting the results? You above ran a NAMED query, and got the results. You can also use createQuery and define your query then get the results. No idea beyond that what you're asking. Where you PUT the results is up to you as it is in any Java app

Comment: My issue is getting the results of a query into a form that can be displayed to the user, ultimately in a GUI.  At present I am placing the results of queries in lists of the appropriate class, and then using the related "get" methods to display the values.  But that method doesn't work if the query contains data from multiple tables.